# Making a movie on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, video, jupyter-notebook

Sorry guys, I am still quite new to Python. I am trying to create animations/movies and the only way i could think of doing this was saving each plot and then somehow stitching them all together. My problem is I am not too sure on how to do this. I read you could use ffmpeg but I was not really sure how to utilize this on Jupyter Notebook.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Matplotlib provides tools for this - https://towardsdatascience.com/animations-with-matplotlib-d96375c5442c

Comment: if you have images then you can use `subprocess` to run any external program - ie. `ffmpeg` or you can use python module [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python). I uses python to run ffmpeg [concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) to join images from Raspberry Pi camera and create video.

Comment: @furas Okay thanks a lot. I'm sorry I am quite new so how do i use this python module. Do i simply type pip install ffmpeg-python in the terminal. If so, what do i do once thats complete. Do i need to write import ffmpeg on my document?

Comment: you have to always use `import` to use some module - read documentation for this module beacause I don't use it. I use directly `ffmepg` like this `subprocess.run("ffmpeg -i *.jpg output.mp4", shell=True)`

Comment: @furas ah perfect. Thanks so much for the help! Appreciate it

Comment: BTW: to use module `ffmpeg-python` you have to also install [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)